# Как из простого класса вызвать метод из класса ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
 @IBOutlet weak var rateStatus: UITextField!
  func Test(){
    rateStatus.text=Optional(String(""))
  } 
 }

 class TestExample{
  func Exmp(){
    //Как выздвать функцию  Test из класса ViewController
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте код приведенный ниже

```
class TestExample{

   func Exmp(){
       let vc = ViewController() //Создаем экземпляр класса View Controller
       vc.Test()
   }

}
```

Comment: Мне это не подойдет,  так как это класс ViewController и в нем есть (UIButton,UITextField и тд), а пересоздавать не вариант

Comment: Если вы используете segue для переходов, вы можете получить ссылку на ViewController, если вы него переходите, в методе prepareForSegue

Comment: Так же можете попробовать следующее 

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
controller.Test()

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите напрямую вызвать - второй класс должен знать о первом. А можно по-ленивому, c использованием `NotificationCenter`:

1 В `viewDidload` контроллера регистрируете наблюдатель:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(test), name: NSNotification.Name("Test"), object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@objc func test() {
    //Все что необходимо здесь выполнить
}
```

2 В нужный момент посылаете уведомление (Ваш метод Exmp())

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Test"), object: nil)
```

`ViewController` его принимает и выполняет `test()`